# Component Event Not working - parameter value not showing in JS Console

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-events

I added these Console.logs to RowsPerPageController.js

[image]

selectedValue prints "5" to Console as expected
But it seems "5" is never added as a param to the event.
Furthermore, in Test1Controller.js I have a console log at the very beginning of function rowsPerPageChange. That never prints, which may indicate the event is not actually firing or being caught by the Parent's handler.

I've been at this for some hours and had another pair of eyes on it :| Your help is much appreciated!

My Parent Component: Test1.cmp

```
<aura:component access="public" implements="force:appHostable,lightning:isUrlAddressable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="FirebirdOrganizationsController">  
<aura:attribute name="quanitySelected" type="String" default="0"/>

<aura:handler name="RowsPerPageEvent" 
                event="c:RowsPerPageEvent" 
                action="{!c.rowsPerPageChange}" />

<c:RowsPerPage/>
```

Test1Controller.js

```
({
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {    


},
rowsPerPageChange : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log("In Parent JS: rowsPerPageChange function");
    component.set("v.quanitySelected", event.getParam("rowsPerPage"));
    var test = component.get("v.quanitySelected");
    console.log(test);
    //helper.getDataBasedOnRowsPerPage(component, helper);      
}
```

})

RowsPerPageEvent.evt

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT" description="Rows Per Page Event">
<aura:attribute name="rowsPerPage" type="String" default="0"/>
```

My Child Component: RowsPerPage.cmp

```
<aura:component>
<aura:registerEvent name="RowsPerPageEventChange" type="c:RowsPerPageEvent" />

<div>
    <div scope="col">Show</div>
    <ui:inputSelect value="20" aura:id="rowsPerPageSelect" change="{!c.rowsPerPageChange}">
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="5" value="5"/>
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="10" value="10"/>
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="20" value="20"/>
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="30" value="30"/>
    </ui:inputSelect>
</div>
```

RowsPerPageController.js

```
({
rowsPerPageChange : function(component, event, helper) 
{       
    var selectedValue = component.find("rowsPerPageSelect").get("v.value");
    console.log("### selectedValue: ", selectedValue);
    var rowsPerPageChangeEvent =
        component.getEvent("RowsPerPageEventChange");
        console.log("getEvent: ", component.getEvent("RowsPerPageEventChange"));
        rowsPerPageChangeEvent.setParams({
            "rowsPerPage" : selectedValue
        });
    console.log("getEvent: ", component.getEvent("RowsPerPageEventChange"));    
    console.log("### rowsPerPageChangeEvent: ", rowsPerPageChangeEvent);

    rowsPerPageChangeEvent.fire();      
}
```

})

Comment: Something easy to try, remove 'name=" RowsPerPageEvent"' from your event Test1.cmp markup.  This has fixed events not working properly for me in the past.

Comment: If that doesn't work, I recommend using the syntax here when firing your event. 

Change the following in your controller.js:
'component.getEvent("RowsPerPageEventChange")'

To the following:
var rowsPerPageEvent = $A.get("e.c:RowsPerPageEvent");

Comment: The first thing didn't work. I implemented your second suggestion and got this...  Uncaught Action failed: c:RowsPerPage$controller$rowsPerPageChange [Cannot read property 'markup://c:RowsPerPageEvent' of undefined]

Comment: I created a new Event, just to make sure that wasn't corrupt. The new event is called RowsPerPageEvent2.  Now I get this error...   Uncaught Action failed: c:RowsPerPage$controller$rowsPerPageChange [Cannot read property 'setParam' of undefined]

Comment: var rowsPerPageChangeEvent = $A.get("e.c:RowsPerPageEvent2");

Comment: Did you register the new event in your markup? Make sure in your register markup that your name="" is camelcase, don't start it with a capital letter. event names are really touchy.

<aura:registerEvent name="rowsPerPageEvent2" type="c:RowsPerPageEvent2"/>

handler should be:

<aura:handler
                event="c:RowsPerPageEvent2" 
                action="{!c.rowsPerPageChange}" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in my original post is fine except for...

name in the handler (on Parent .cmp)

```
    <aura:handler name="RowsPerPageEvent" 
                event="c:RowsPerPageEvent" 
                action="{!c.rowsPerPageChange}"/>
```

did not match name in the registerEvent (on Child .cmp)

```
<aura:registerEvent name="RowsPerPageEventChange" type="c:RowsPerPageEvent" />
```

ALSO, includeFacets="true" was needed on the handler

So replace handler in my original post with this, and it works perfectly...

```
    <aura:handler name="RowsPerPageEventChange" 
                event="c:RowsPerPageEvent" 
                action="{!c.rowsPerPageChange}"
                includeFacets="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I felt bad we weren't able to solve it yesterday, so I went and created a mock of your components in a dev box.  I have the event firing, listening, and logging on both ends properly. Here's the code:

Parent.cmp:

```
<aura:attribute name="quanitySelected" type="String" default="0"/>

<aura:handler event="c:RowsPerPageEvent" 
              action="{!c.rowsPerPageChange}" />

<c:RowsPerPage/>
```

Parent.js

```
rowsPerPageChange : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log(event.getParam('rowsPerPage'));
}
```

Event component did not change - use your original one.

RowsPerPage.cmp:

```
<aura:registerEvent name="rowsPerPageEvent" type="c:RowsPerPageEvent" />

<div>
    <div scope="col">Show</div>
    <ui:inputSelect value="20" aura:id="rowsPerPageSelect" change="{!c.rowsPerPageChange}">
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="5" value="5"/>
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="10" value="10"/>
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="20" value="20"/>
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="30" value="30"/>
    </ui:inputSelect>
</div>
```

RowsPerPageController.js:

```
rowsPerPageChange : function(component, event, helper) {       
    var selectedValue = component.find("rowsPerPageSelect").get("v.value");
    console.log("### selectedValue: ", selectedValue);
     var rowsPerPageEvent = $A.get("e.c:RowsPerPageEvent");
    rowsPerPageEvent.setParams({
        "rowsPerPage": selectedValue
    });
    console.log('prefire')
    rowsPerPageEvent.fire();

}
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon! I'm tied up at the moment, but will definitely try this by tomorrow and circle back.

Comment: Just got this error...     Error  force-app/main/default/aura/Test1/Test1.cmp  A aura:handler that specifies an event="" attribute must handle an application event. Either change the aura:event to have type="APPLICATION" or alternately change the aura:handler to specify a name="" attribute.

Comment: added Name, now getting... Uncaught Action failed: c:RowsPerPage$controller$rowsPerPageChange [Cannot read property 'markup://c:RowsPerPageEvent' of undefined]